# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default) on project ors: The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid

Tags: java, maven

When i am trying to execute **mvn -DskipTests=true -Passembly assembly:directory exec:exec** command to make binary i am getting 
 **Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default) on project ors: The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid** error. i have also applied **Source Target 1.8** inside configuration but still i am getting the same error.

```
<profile>
      <id>execute</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.marketcetera.ors.OrderRoutingSystem</mainClass>
          <systemProperties>
              <systemProperty>
                  <key>org.marketcetera.appDir</key>
                  <value>src/test/cmd_exec</value>
              </systemProperty>
          </systemProperties>
          <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- Command-line execution of the ORS (with DB initialization). -->
    <profile>
      <id>executeDBInit</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.marketcetera.ors.DBInit</mainClass>
        <arguments>
          <argument>org.marketcetera.ors.OrderRoutingSystem</argument>
        </arguments>
        <systemProperties>
          <systemProperty>
            <key>org.marketcetera.appDir</key>
            <value>src/test/cmd_exec</value>
          </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- Command-line execution of the miniscule exchange. -->
    <profile>
      <id>exchange</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.marketcetera.ors.exchange.Main</mainClass>
        <arguments>
          <argument>exchange.xml</argument>
        </arguments>
        <systemProperties>
          <systemProperty>
            <key>org.marketcetera.appDir</key>
            <value>src/test/cmd_exec</value>
          </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- Security administration utility. -->
    <profile>
      <id>cli</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.marketcetera.ors.security.ORSAdminCLI</mainClass>
        <!-- -Dexec.args="-u admin ..." -->
        <systemProperties>
          <systemProperty>
            <key>org.marketcetera.appDir</key>
            <value>src/test/cmd_exec</value>
          </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- Assembly. -->
    <profile>
      <id>assembly</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                      <goals><goal>single</goal></goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <formats><format>dir</format></formats>
                          <descriptors>
                              <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                          </descriptors>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                      <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>
                      <configuration>
              <executable>${perl.path}</executable>
                          <arguments>
                              <argument>../tools/scripts/createScript.pl</argument>
                              <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</argument>
                              <argument>ors</argument>
                              <argument>org.marketcetera.ors.OrderRoutingSystem</argument>
                              <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</argument>
                              <argument>orsadmin</argument>
                              <argument>org.marketcetera.ors.security.ORSAdminCLI</argument>
                          </arguments>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 5):

As of `exec-maven-plugin` version 1.6.0, it appears `<configuration>` sections within `<execution>` blocks are ignored unless you specify an id.

Try changing your command line, substituting **exec:exec@foo** for **exec:exec** with the plugin block changed to include an id **foo** as follows:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>foo</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>
                  <configuration>
          <executable>${perl.path}</executable>
                      <arguments>
                          <argument>../tools/scripts/createScript.pl</argument>
                          <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</argument>
                          <argument>ors</argument>
                          <argument>org.marketcetera.ors.OrderRoutingSystem</argument>
                          <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</argument>
                          <argument>orsadmin</argument>
                          <argument>org.marketcetera.ors.security.ORSAdminCLI</argument>
                      </arguments>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this error by specifying the required plugin in pom.xml as follows

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>com.ocloud.Alarm.App</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify `perl.path` variable in `<executable>` tag.

```
<executable>${perl.path}</executable>
```

Add this to your pom parent:

```
<properties>
    <perl.path>path/to/perl</perl.path>       
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you much for youe suggetion but i have already maintained <executable>${perl.path}</executable> in <configuration> tag of last <plugin> tag

Comment: I see. But did you specify value of perl.path variable?

Comment: i have specified the value of perl.path variable in System Variables "C:\Program Files\strawberry\perl\bin".

Answer (score 1):

This error `The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid` can also happen if the `exec-maven-plugin` plugin is configured in a child maven module and you run the command from the parent directory.

To fix that, simple change your working directory to where the plugin is used.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile before execution

```
clean compiler:compile exec:java
```